# Determining which page an item might be on?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Given the MySQL primary key of a particular element in a paginated result set, is there a function to get the page number that element is in?

If not, what is some pseudocode that can help me get there? Note that primary keys can be deleted and there will be 'gaps' in the sequence so simple arithmetic alone might not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as amountBefore FROM `table` WHERE `id` <= 'id'

page = ceil(amountBefore / amountPerPage)
```

Comment: smart one :) but <= will be better in the Where clause

Comment: won't work if you need to order by anything besides id (or anything that is not id or in sync with id) also could be tricky if you have a composed key and/or your key is not numeric

Comment: tbh, I did not understand your solution or why it worked... so I tried the problem on paper, "found" the answer, and was about to answer myself when I saw that this solution already says the same thing, PLUS I forgot about the <= and was only going to use <.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Your welcome, I guess it was just a case of thinking to difficult :P

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(POSITION/15) FROM (
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as POSITION, id 
    FROM table_name, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
    ORDER BY published DESC
 ) t WHERE id = 17;
```

( given your id being `17`, and your items per page being `15`, and the property you are ordering by is `published`)

But be aware that any solution (if you do it in PHP even more so) is somewhat wastefull since a lot of data is temporarilly collected - if it is in any way possibile try to receive the current page via routing/get parameters/the url.

Comment: Thanks for the latter suggestion, but the problem is not to get the current page, but to find the element's page number without actually paginating.

Comment: @aditya menon well thats why i said "if it is in any way possibile" :) in any case as far as I understand it my thing should work

Comment: Hi, I tried `SELECT FLOOR( POSITION /10 )
FROM (
SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 AS POSITION, domain_id
FROM domains, (
SELECT @rownum :=0
)r
ORDER BY domain_id DESC
)t
WHERE domain_id =18`

In my domains table, and I always get 0 as the output (in phpMyAdmin) - what am I doing wrong?